# Can't connect to Azure webapp using work account authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am creating an Azure web application that serves as a gateway to our organization's database. As I don't want our database to be accessible by the whole internet, I want to use some kind of authentication.

I achieved this authentication by following these steps:

1) Microsoft Visual Studio -> File -> New -> Project -> ASP.NET Web Application

2) Select MVC and click on the 'change authentication' button

3) Select Company or School as authentication method and fill in the right domain name

4) Now I publish the web application and browse to the link

5) I get forwarded to the login.microsoftonline page and asked to log in with my organization's email.

6) After logging in with my organization's email, localhost can't connect to the web application and throws the following error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

If I follow the same process as above but select no authentication, everything works fine. In addition, all our organizational addresses are on Azure Active Directory.

Does anyone know why I can't connect to the application and/or has suggestions to solve this?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's trying to forward you to localhost after authentication. The redirect_uri is specified wrong for some reason.

Comment: where can I change this uri? And I thought it was redirected right as i get forwarded to the login.microsoftonline page first

Comment: Yeah but the redirect back to your app is wrong. It's specified as the redirect_uri in the login URL. Usually this is configured somewhere in the app, could you show your authentication config code? The Azure Web App URL needs to be added to the valid reply URLs for the app in Azure AD configuration in Azure portal also.

Comment: That might indeed help! I will try to change this redirectUri from the web config     <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44339/" /> to 'https://<my web app name>.azurewebsites.com

Comment: I tried replacing the RedirectUri in the web.config to <my webapp's name>.azurewebservices.net but after logging in it keeps redirecting to localhost. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by going to app services -> Authentication/Verification -> authenticate with Azure Active Directory. Thereafter, go to Azure Active Directory and add the web application's URL to reply URL's / properties of the AD instance.